# Is there a way to use build a web page using only objects in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net

I'm not sure how exactly to word this correctly, but the gist is we already have a system that receives scripts from a server which provide a layout of some UI. We dynamically render this UI for the desktop client (WPF). We would like to do something similar for the web to provide some subset of functionality where we don't want to install the thick client. While simply creating a server control that renders html/aspx strings e.g.  is fairly easy, generating text that handles a rich ui experience via JS/AJAX etc... not so much. If we used Java, Vaadin would be perfect, but Windows Silverlight requires a plugin. All the information I've found on ASP involves simply writing text to the response output, but I'd like to...

1. Get a request into a custom HttpModule.
2. Query for the appropriate script and render it via System.Web objects in C#.
3. Return the objects or a Page or something to ASP.Net to serve the user.
4. Handle events and provide general interactivity to the user.

Is something like this possible in ASP.Net and how would I interject myself into the page life cycle so that I can return my dynamically created Page instance or get to the one being created and add to it?

Comment: At the fear of giving you bad advice, I am looking for some of this information myself.   I have sort-of decided to look at MVC as it allows you to somewhat simply connect to either data (or service) and appears to want to do some of the work for you.

Comment: Your custom HttpModule can route requests to an ASPX that dynamically creates the controls.  Which part are you stuck on?  Each of your bullet points should probably be their own question.

Comment: How is it a problem that Silverlight requires a plugin, but it's okay for Java? How do you think Java is doing this? I mean, there are plenty of other problems with Silverlight, but in this case it seems like kind of a double standard.

Comment: Vaadin doesn't use a plugin. It's a web application framework where you develop in java and it generates a rich internet application using HTML5 and Javascript. From the developer side he's simply using Java and the Vaadin API to create an interactive and powerful site. From the user's perspective they are just going to a website so nothing to install.

Comment: @David I can write text to the response in Begin/EndRequest, but don't seem to have access to the Page or a way to dynamically alter it.

Also, the bullets are simply the work flow, #3 is really the only question I meant framed at the end of my post.

Comment: Rather than a handler, could you just start with an empty .aspx page, and add controls dynamically in the Page_Load event in code-behind?

Comment: I tried something similar but couldn't figure out how to add the controls to a form and kept getting "Control 'XXX' of type 'XXX' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server." Now I'm trying to create a custom server control that would be in a form on a blank page and see if it can dynamically add controls and respond to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a little test page.  Maybe this is enough to get you going.  All kinds of places you can go with this, along the lines of custom controls with their own markup and event handlers.  I hope this helps!

**Test.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="DynamicFormTest.Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Test.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace DynamicFormTest
{
    public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button1 = new Button();
            button1.Text = "Hello World";
            button1.Attributes["onclick"] = "alert('Hello!')";
            this.form1.Controls.Add(button1);
        }
    }
}
```